# How to concatenate strings in PHP?

Tags: php, concatenation

I am having issues with php, I wish to concatenate this.

```
'<a href="?param='$_GET["param"]-1'" title="">Prev</a> <a href="?param='$_GET["param"]+1'" title="">Next</a>'
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability in this code too, don't use `$_GET` values without escaping/filtering them.

Comment: I would say that if you are a complete PHP beginner, work your way through a good tutorial first, before trying to strike out on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dot to concatenate strings

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php